# Firefox on iOS reloads old page although history and cache cleared

Tags: ios, firefox, browser-cache, browser-history

I am working on a web page, which I want to test on my iPhone. However, when I visit the website from my phone in either Firefox or Safari it is an old version of the website that opens. I have tried to clear cache and history as described [here](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Privacy/Clear-browsing-history-in-Firefox-for-iOS/ta-p/36039), but it is still the old website that appears. I have also tried to de-connect my Firefox account and restart both the app and the phone. I have checked in a browser on my computer and here I see the new website and any changes implemented instantaneously.

Do anyone have similar experiences with such an issue and how to solve it?

Edit 1: After a while (couple of hours) I tried again and it was indeed the new page in the mobile browser. I still don't however understand why there is latency in a mobile browser and not elsewhere, i.e. where and why is the old page cached on a mobile device even though history and cache has been cleared?

Edit 2: I have now also discovered that the same issue applies to all other non-mobile browsers than FirefoxDeveloperEdition, so this browser must be doing something the others don't.

Comment: Can you show us HTTP headers of a response that contains old version of  your website? You can use [Firefox Network Monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) to get them.

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev thanks for you comment - I however solved in the meantime by using `cache-purge` from the SSH service from my provider...

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues in past. It depends upon your hosting provider. Usually it takes no time to update web pages but sometimes average hosting sucks.

Try opening webpages in incognito mode/private mode.

Comment: I just don't understand why it is an issue only on mobile devices and not on other devices if it is an issue with the hosting provider?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by running `cache-purge` from my provider's SSH service.